# Pandas Selecting Rows with common item in column with list value

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/vesuvius13/serial-killers-dataset) I am trying to see if there is an overlap in the years killers were active for each country.

```
df['start_year'] = df['Years active'].apply(lambda x:x.split(' ',1)[0]).astype('int')
df['last_year'] = df['Years active'].apply(lambda x:x.split(' ',2)[2]).astype('int')

df['range']=df.apply(lambda x : list(range(x['start_year'],x['last_year']+1)),1)
```

I am clueless as to how process from here. Can some one please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick example to show a pairwise apply:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['d',4]], columns=['label','val'])
>>> df.apply(lambda x: df.apply(lambda y: x.val + y.val, axis=1).to_list(), axis=1, result_type='expand')

   0  1  2  3
0  2  3  4  5
1  3  4  5  6
2  4  5  6  7
3  5  6  7  8
```

The result comes out as a dataframe with each pairwise operation as a value.

If you replace the `x.val + y.val` with your code to compare the active years it should work fine.
I would suggest that function return a boolean.
Something along the lines of:

```
def matching_range(start1, end1, start2, end2):
    ...
    return True or False
```

And in the apply it would look like:
`matching_range(x.start_year, x.end_year, y.start_year, y.end_year)`
Which would give you a table of matches like the following.

```
   0  1  2  3
0  T  F  T  T
1  F  T  F  F
2  T  F  T  F
3  T  F  F  T
```